# tastypie: use PUT Partially Updating An Existing Resource succeed! why?

Tags: tastypie

when I use **put**,but not **patch**, successfully **Partially** updated my resource , I'm confused!

can **put** use as a **patch**?

according to [django-tastypie readthedocs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html)

> A PUT request requires that the entire resource representation be enclosed. Missing fields may cause errors, or be filled in by default values.

my development env:

> django 1.5
>   django-tastypie 0.9.15

a resource code looks like:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        #allowed_methods = ['get']
        # no permissions checks are performed.
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
```